# Problems Android studio No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

I've been searching for hours and I can't figure what's happening on my Android studio project that is broken.

I've just started a new project, did some coding and when I get to layout development just tried to add a custom toggle buton, have add a png file to drawables and a selector XML to change background, of course I've selected it on main layout XML.

Anyway when I try to run it, I get always the same error

```
Error:(13, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/boton_on').
```

That's my selector if this helps:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/boton_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/boton_on" android:state_checked="false"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: may be there is no image named `boton_on` in your drawable folder.

Comment: post XML of your "boton_on.xml". If you don't have it, well this is the problem. You should have a "boton_on.xml" custom layout which works altogether with this XML layout you posted.

Comment: boton.xml is not required if it is an image.

Comment: Does `boton_on` exists in Drawable ? is of same spelling ?

Comment: boton_on is a png image that is on drawable folder , it's correctly spelled , anyway i've focused on it and verified that everithing is correctly named.

Answer (score 0):

buton_on, either image or xml not found: 
may be not present OR misspelled here which might be button_on 
(use ctrl+space suggestions to avoid these type of issues)